# xml.etree.ElementTree returns Object adress instead of Value

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to get value from xml, using xml.etree.ElementTree

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/?') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

print(root.findall('recording'))
```

but what I'm getting is:

```
<Element 'recording' at 0x000001D871642E50>
```

searched url-request content is False on 4th line:

```
<vmix>
  <version>24.0.0.51</version>
  <edition>Trial</edition>
  <recording>False</recording>
</vmix>
```

P.S. print(root.findall('recording').text) doesn't works too:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'attribute text is not
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findall() returns a list so you need to iterate in the list to access the text attribut

you can also use find() which returns the first 'recording' element found

```
for records in root.findall('recording'):
   print(r.text)

//or

print(root.find('recording').text)
```